# Restarting Blender with a Script

Tags: python, scripting, command-line, windows

I am trying to create an operator that restarts Blender. This script has worked for me in the past:

```py
import bpy
import subprocess

blender_exe = bpy.app.binary_path
subprocess.Popen([blender_exe, "-con", "--python-expr", "import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.recover_last_session()"])
bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
```

I'm now using Blender 3.5 on Windows 11 Pro Version 22H2. Blender quits, but never reopens. If I just run the `subprocess`, it will open the last session. Blender or Windows is quitting both sessions. Is there a way to only quit the old session?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me [huge thank you to Ray Molenkamp (LazyDodo) on blender.chat]:

```py
import bpy,os,subprocess

blender_exe = bpy.app.binary_path
head, tail = os.path.split(blender_exe)
blender_launcher = os.path.join(head,"blender-launcher.exe")
subprocess.run([blender_launcher, "-con", "--python-expr", "import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.recover_last_session()"])
bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) accepts a startinfo argument, which provides for passing flags to WINDOWS CreateProcess().

The flag DETACHED_PROCESS may be what you need;

```
import bpy
import subprocess

blender_exe = bpy.app.binary_path

si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags = subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS
subprocess.Popen([blender_exe, "-con", "--python-expr", "import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.recover_last_session()"], startupinfo=si)

bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response and code. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I've also tried terminating the Blender app by the process ID instead of `bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()`.

Comment: You're welcome @dr-pontchartrain, sorry my initial guess didn't solve it for you. I am not able to test this on a Windows system, but perhaps the flag you need is one of `subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` or `subprocess.CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB`. If you try either and it works I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions. Those flags didn't work for me. I'm not sure if this issue is one particular to my environment or not, but hopefully the `blender-launcher` & `subprocess.run` route will work for other Windows users experiencing this.